# Reach dictionary data within dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

How do I reach the second integer (key) within the following dictionary in Swift? And, while were at it, how would I reach the strings within the second dictionary?

```
var activeCustomers = Dictionary<Int, Dictionary<Int, Dictionary<String, String>>>()
```

I tried writing (for example) var test: Int = activeCustomers[1][1] but that did not work. It said that the dictionary did not have a member named subscript.

Comment: Have you tried `activeCustomers[1]?[1]`? Dictionary subscripts return optionals (contrary to array subscripts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that accessing a `Dictionary` via its subscript, returns an `Optional`. You'll need to unwrap it first.

Testing on a Playground (Swift 1.2) this code works:

```
var activeCustomers = Dictionary<Int, Dictionary<Int, Dictionary<String, String>>>()
var d1 = ["a": "b", "c": "d"]
var d2 = [1: d1]
activeCustomers = [1: d2]
if let d3 = activeCustomers[1] {
    var d4 = d3[1]
}
```

Or, if you know the key exists in the dictionary, you can avoid the `if let` and unwrap the optional directly

```
var d4 = activeCustomers[1]?[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. :) Though, how would I **_get_** the key (second int), to store it in a variable for later use. For example: Dictionary<1, Dictionary<62, Dictionary<"Test1", "Test2">>>, how would I get the integer: 62?

Comment: Actually, I'm running into a more alerting issue regarding this. http://pastebin.com/dLkfiAGw With that code I am getting an error when it unwraps an optional value - why? How do I fix this, and, am I accessing the (populated) activeCustomers dictionary correctly?

Comment: @Tice You cannot unwrap the value if the value is nil. That's why the `if let` is the best way to unwrap it. And that's the reason your app is crashing.

Comment: @Tice In your dictionary is no key with the value of `indexPath.row`. Log it to the console and check if all the keys you expect are there (remember `indexPath.row` is zero-indexed). If so make sure you're returning the right amount of cells in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` (or what it's called).

Comment: @Marcos Crispino `var d4 = activeCustomers[1]?[1]` doesn't unwrap it directly as you said in your answer, it will still return an optional, to unwrap it directly you need to use `var d4 = activeCustomers[1]![1]`

Comment: @HAS In my case the indexPath.row value does in fact represent the first key in the dictionary. Thank you, though, for the tip regarding indexPath.row being zero-indexed - changed my code to fix that! For the sake of my code working I chose to unwrap my dictionaries via if-statements. :)